Determining the continuity of multivariable function $f$ at the point $(0,0)$
I want to determine whether the function $ f $ is continuous at the point $ (0,0) $, this is how far i got.
$$
f(x, y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1 - \cos{(x^2 + y^2)}}{(x^2 + y^2)x^2 y^2} & \text{if } x^2 + y^2 \neq 0, \\\ 0 & \text{if } x^2 + y^2 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
To do this, we need to show that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{1 - \cos{(x^2 + y^2)}}{(x^2 + y^2) x^2 y^2} = 0
\end{equation}
We convert to polar coordinates, where $ x = r \cos{\varphi}$ and $ y = r \sin{\varphi} :$
$$
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{1 - \cos{(x^2 + y^2)}}{(x^2 + y^2) x^2 y^2} = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos{r^2}}{r^6 \cos^2{\varphi} \sin^2{\varphi}}
$$
As $r \to 0$, we expand $1 - \cos{r^2}$ using the Maclaurin series. Using the fact that
$
\cos{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \dots,
$
we obtain
$$
1 - \cos{r^2} = \frac{r^4}{2} - \frac{r^8}{24} + \frac{r^{12}}{720} + \dots
$$
As $ r \to 0 $, terms like $ \frac{r^8}{24}$ and beyond become negligibly small, so we can approximate:
$
1 - \cos{r^2} \approx \frac{r^4}{2}
$
Substituting this back into the original limit:
$$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos{r^2}}{r^6 \cos^2{\varphi} \sin^2{\varphi}} = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\frac{r^4}{2}}{r^6 \cos^2{\varphi} \sin^2{\varphi}} = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2 r^2 \cos^2{\varphi} \sin^2{\varphi}}
\end{equation}
$$
Does this mean, that the limit doesnt exist if $r \to 0$? If so then why?

Limit along $\phi=\frac {\pi} 4$ does not exist.

@geetha290krm, does this formally conclude that the function is not continuous, at $(0;0)$?

Yes, it does. For continuity at $(0,0)$ the limit has to exist in whatever way you approach $(0,0)$.

@geetha290krm Sorry, might be a stupid question, but why doesn't the limit exist? the sine and cosine are both defined at $\varphi = \frac{\pi}{4}$? Shouldn't the limit just be positive infinity?

Do you know the exact values of sine and cosine at that point?

$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for both of them.

For continuity the limit has to be $f(0,0)=0$

So by that logic there are no angles we can approach $(0;0)$ from so that the limit equals 0, hence it doesn't converge?
